# RxSwift toArray does not compile with generic parameter

Tags: swift, generics, reactive-programming, rx-swift

RxSwift `toArray` is not working for me when using generics:

```
struct SaveModelsCommand<M> where M:Model {

    let models:[M]

    func create() -> Observable<[M]> {

        let cloudKitRecords:[CKRecord] = models.map({ 
            // convert models to CKRecords
            ... 
        })

        return SaveRecordsCommand(cloudKitRecords)
            .createObservable()
            .flatMap({ savedRecords in
                // convert array to multiple emissions so we can iterate it
                return Observable.from(savedRecords)
            })
            .flatMap({ (record:CKRecord) -> M in
                // convert CKRecord back to a model (aka M)
                ... create model (e.g. Member) ...
                return model
            })
            // convert back to a single emission (array)
            .toArray() // <<<<< ERROR
    }
}
```

Here is the error:

> Cannot convert return expression of type 'Observable<[M.E]>' (aka 'Observable>') to return type 'Observable<[M]>' (aka 'Observable>')

The only difference that I can see in the return type is `M.E` vs `M`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`flatMap` expects the closure to return an `Observable<M>`, not just a plain `M`:

```
.flatMap({ (record:CKRecord) -> Observable<M> in
    // convert CKRecord back to a model (aka M)
    //... create model (e.g. Member) ...
    return Observable.just(model)
})
```

Alternatively, you can use `map` and just return an `M`:

```
.map({ (record:CKRecord) -> M in
    // convert CKRecord back to a model (aka M)
    //... create model (e.g. Member) ...
    return model
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I went with `map` since that more closely represents the intent.